# How to not feed in certain inputs in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Suppose I have a Fully Connected Neural Network like this in Tensorflow:

```
input_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numInputs])
input_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numInputs2])
fc_1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input_1, num_outputs=128, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
fc_2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input_2, num_outputs=128, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
fc_3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc_1 + fc_2, num_outputs=100, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
output = tf.nn.softmax(fc_3)
```

This network takes two inputs, each of which go through a fully connected layer. Then, these are added up, and passed through another fully connected layer, and finally a softmax is computed.

Let's say I train this network on some task, and then for another task, I want to use the same network, but not `input_2`. Thus, I will not have `input_2`. I am ok with ignoring `fc_2` or not ignoring it, but the rest of the network will be the same as before. Is this possible? If so, how can you do it, and if not why not? I don't want to just save the parameters of this model and load it into the other model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second network, you can pass a tensor of zeros as the values of `input_2`. Then your `fc_2` will be all zeros and when you sum it with `fc_1`, it will have no effect.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!